# How to scroll to next item with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I've seen some apps that have this effect that I find interesting but don't know how to achieve it. It has a collectionView or a tableView where you click an item it shows the data of that item. Then when you swipe left or right it shows either the previous item or the next item. This is how my app looks like at the moment.

[image]

When you click an image it opens another viewController that only contains an image that looks like this.

[image]

This is where I get completely stuck. I'm thinking that I might have to use a UIPageViewController but not sure. I would really appreciate any help, link to a tutorial or really anything that helps. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the detail view controller (the one with the fullscreen photo), you'll need to have another collection view with all the data from the original collection view.

Each fullscreen photo will be a collection view cell, and you can set the collection view's `isPagingEnabled` property to true to get a paging effect.

Comment: Hey nathan. I was able to achieve the effect I wanted. However I used a UIPageViewController instead. So without your advice I wouldn't  of been able to do it. Thanks :)